# Compare objects from the parse with the hardcoded objects in the application

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an application which saves data both locally and on the parse.Whenever my application is opened a set of hardcoded data gets saved in the parse.Now the first time it saves perfectly but after the second launch duplicated are created for obvious reasons.Now i know i have to compare the objects but with what actually because the hardcoded data doesn't contain an objectId and the localId access is not supported.Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a property let's say `isSynced` to identify that this record is already synced to the server. Once the record get saved you can mark this as `isSynced = true`.

Comment: And saving this isSynced to nsuserdefaults... other way is to use dispatch_once method to do it exactly one time.